# Save issue in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Table Structure:

```
1   ID  int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT  
2   filename    varchar(11) latin1_swedish_ci        
3   status  int(2)          
4   type    int(11) 
5   created_at  timestamp       
6   updated_at  timestamp           


Route::get('/verify1/{data}',function($data){

$task=   FileLocation::where('ID',"=",$data)->first();
$task->status = 1;
$task->save();   

});
```

Problem: I tried to return $data. It displays $data=1. I have ID=1 in the table too. Why it doesn't save? Could you please help. This issue screws up my head. I am new to laravel.  Thank you.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Are you sure you data is not saved? What's the initial value of `status` column BEFORE running this route?

Comment: Hello Marcin, Thanks for your reply. Initial value of status is 0. Final value of status is 0 too.  I don't get any error.

Comment: Are you sure you are running correct url in your browser? Could you show us the `FileLocation` model and show us what's the table name of table you showed us in question?

Comment: class FileLocation extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

 use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

 
 protected $table = 'files';

 
 protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');
 
} 
ID filename status type created_at updated_at


1 image1.jpg 0 1 2016-01-09 11:37:52 2016-01-09 05:20:10


2 image2.jpg 0 2  2016-01-09 12:49:48 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: Could you add `dd($task);` before `$task->status = 1;` and include result in your question?

Comment: object(FileLocation)#169 (20) {
  ["attributes":protected]=>
  array(6) {
    ["ID"]=>    int(1)
    ["filename"]=>    string(10) "image1.jpg"
    ["status"]=>    string(1) "1"
    ["type"]=>    int(1)
    ["created_at"]=>    string(19) "2016-01-09 11:37:52"
    ["updated_at"]=>
    string(19) "2016-01-09 05:20:10"
  }
  ["original":protected]=>
  array(6) {
    ["ID"]=>    int(1)
    ["filename"]=>    string(10) "image1.jpg"
    ["status"]=>    int(0)
    ["type"]=>    int(1)
    ["created_at"]=>    string(19) "2016-01-09 11:37:52"
    ["updated_at"]=>    string(19) "2016-01-09 05:20:10"
  }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100219/discussion-between-marcin-nabialek-and-scorpion).

Comment: try using `query builder` update method. see if it's working or not. `$task->update(['status'=>1])`

Answer (score 0):

in `FileLocation` model class add  protected `$fillable = array('status');`. `Mass Assignment` will not allow to update this data untill laravel will not know it is ok, to update it. If all data can be changed than add protected `$guarded = array();` This and more info on this sub. can be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#mass-assignment)

In shortcut:

Once model is created, some attributes, are protected by laravel. This is in case of sensitive data, like: `'id', 'created_at'` etc. By default all attributes are protected. It can be change in two ways: (white or black)list. These are protected $fillable or protected $guarded arrays that contain attributes to care of.

Comment: Doesn't $fillable and $guarded only affect mass-assignment (`->fill(...)`) while direct assignment, which the question uses, should still work?